# The use of the preposition "to" in the third conditional when talking about places

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me please if it is correct to the preposition to in the following sentence.

> If I had studied well, I would have been **to** California.
>
> If I had had the money, I would have been **to** the university of Cambridge.

Would it be better to use the preposition *in* in the first sentence, and *at* in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odd sound of these sentences is not because of the preposition "to".

The reason they sound strange and not quite idiomatic is because of the verb choice.

The tense is correct, "would have [participle]", but the verb "to go" sounds more idiomatic to me than "to be":

> If I had studied well, I would have **gone** to California.
>
> If I had had the money, I would have **gone** to the **U**niversity of Cambridge.

I have a feeling there may be some regional dialects where "**been**" is OK in this context, but "**gone**" is correct in standard usage, both in the context of "going to a place" and "going to a University".

So to answer your question, there is nothing wrong with "to" in third conditional sentences if you use "to go", but you are correct that if you are going to use "to be", both sentences sound better with your second choice of preposition:

> If I had studied well, I would have been **in** California.
>
> If I had had the money, I would have been **at** the **U**niversity of
>   Cambridge.